# Is the "!=" comparision operator faster than ">"?

Tags: c++, performance, comparison

A really basic question:

Considering an unsigned integer value, we would like to check that is not equal to 0. Using `!=` or `>`, which one would be more efficient to use in C++?

Comment: That depends on the compiler and the machine the code is running on. Not very constructive.

Comment: It depends.  Usually, no difference at all.  But note that your two options deal with negative values differently, so they're not equivalent.

Comment: If this really makes a difference in your code, try it both ways and use a profiler.

Comment: Hmm? Let me think? You could use `!=` for checking if it is not equal to 0 and `>` for checking if it is greater than 0?

Answer (score 5):

Is your application too slow? If it is, the first thing you should do is profile -- this will show you what is causing your program to be slow.

If you aren't having efficiency issues with your program then you shouldn't be worried about this. In fact, worrying about speed at this stage is a bad thing because often people write less readable code in an attempt to improve speed when it's not even an issue.

Comment: Typical SO comment- some people are programming in environment where every little trick can help. If someone asks what is the fastest way to check something is not equal we shouldnt just say "only ask if that is the bottleneck".

Comment: It's typical because it's the right answer. In almost every case, if you're asking whether `>` or `!=` is faster, you're asking the wrong question.